# Java Ant Builder - "Content is not allowed in prolog." .sh

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build, instrumentation

Okay, so I have a .sh build file that I'm trying to add to the build process when running a project in Eclipse.

Inside the .sh file, all I have is:

```
mvn process-classes
```

This is what is returned when I try to build it:

```
 Buildfile: /home/samuel/Dev/workspaces/dauntless-workspace/Dauntless/scripts/instrumentation.sh

 BUILD FAILED
 /home/samuel/Dev/workspaces/dauntless-workspace/Dauntless/scripts/instrumentation.sh:1:    Content is not allowed in prolog.

 Total time: 59 milliseconds
```

Screenshot of the build configuration:

[image]

Thank you for your time,
Samuel Smith

Comment: There are maven plugins for Eclipse which provide integration of maven in to Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Ant files are XML. You might be able to add your script as an External Tool instead (it's the button next to Debug and Run) and then add it as a Builder to your Project.